# Hide quick launch for specific group permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, groups, quick-launch

I have a list which contains multiple users that they will access it from 2 different groups permissions, **Members (Read Only)**, **Visitors(View Only)**.

**What I have tried to do:**

- When they are assigned to a group they are able to see it knowing that View only permission is the same as the group one.
- When I assign the users outside the group as View only permission they are not able to see it. But I want to hide it from group permission because I am using a code that will hide excel feature only for groups.
- Also, I have tried to remove the groups from quick launch, but as result nothing happens and they still are able to see it.

**What I want to achieve**:

- Hide the quick lunch in the left pane of the screen from those 2 groups. But the others group like owners are able to see the Quick lunch.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript code to hide the quick launch when the current user is in the Members group/ Visitors group, you can check the demo below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready( function()

function isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName) {

var userIsInGroup = false;

$.ajax({

async: false,

headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

method: "GET",

url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/groups",

success: function (data) {

data.d.results.forEach( function (value) {

if (value.Title == groupName) {

userIsInGroup = true;

}

});

},

error: function (response) {

console.log(response.status);

},

});

return userIsInGroup;

}

function HideMasterStyles() {

var isMembers=false;

isMembers = isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Members");

if(isMembers)

{ 
$("#sideNavBox").css("display", "none");
}

}

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(HideMasterStyles,'SP.js');

});

</script>
```